# Ubuntu 14.04: Sync Dropbox Folder to SD Card

Tags: 14.04, mount, dropbox, sd-card

My Dropbox folder is on an SD card.  When I have to reboot my computer, Dropbox apparently tries to connect with the folder before it's mounted and returns an error.  I have to sign into Dropbox each time, and it always connects properly.

Is there a way to delay the Dropbox attempt on startup until the SD card is mounted properly?

Thank you!

Comment: How is the SD card mounted? Is it entered in the fstab or is just automounted on login?

Comment: Auto mounted at login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by placing the following script in /etc/rc.local on my machine:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# If there is a device with the label "Storage" mount it to /media/harry/Storage
if [ $(blkid -L Storage) ]; then
        mkdir -p /media/harry/Storage && mount -L Storage /media/harry/Storage || rm -r /media/harry/Storage
fi

exit 0
```

A more general solution would probably be

```
# Get the label for the device, if any
label=$(blkid /dev/<device_name> -s LABEL -o value) 

# If the label is equal to a value, mount it
if ($label = "<device_label>");then
    mkdir -p /media/<username>/$label && mount -L $label /media/<username>/$label || rm -r /media/<username>/$label
fi
```

But I haven't tested it

If you want to see a list of the devices use the blkid command

Good Luck.